# Emulate VB.Net Module in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, module

I just started working in C# after working in VB.Net for a while.  I have a dll that contains frequently used database connection strings (and some other db info) and another dll that contains frequently used directory paths.  When creating an application in VB, I would use these dlls in a Module to set the environment to testing so the databases would point to the QA versions of the databases and the directories would point to my local directories.  When I was ready to publish the application, I would set the environment to production.  It looked something like this.

```
Module MyModule
  Friend MyBizDBs As BizDBs
  Friend MyBizPaths As BizPaths
  Friend TodaysDate As Date

  Friend Sub InitializeModule()
    MyBizDBs = New BizDBs(DBReference.BizDatabases.DBConfig.DB_Environment.QA)
    MyBizPaths = New BizPaths(BizPaths.PathEnvironment.Test)
    TodaysDate = DBReference.BizDatabases.DBMethods.GetTodaysDate
  End Sub
End Module
```

I could then call InitializeModule at the start of the application and whenever a class needed a connection string or a directory or anything else offered by those dlls, it would be pointing to the correct environment.  Moreover, I didn't need to create a new instance of  MyModule each time.  Instead I could simply write:

```
Using sw as new StreamWriter(MyBizPaths.ReconciliationReport)
```

I know C# doesn't have Modules.  I know static classes are similar, but I can't initialize the objects (MyBizDBs and MyBizPaths) to set them to the appropriate environment in static classes.  I'm looking at a C# Singleton, but that reinitializes each time the class is called.  Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do in C#?
Thanks!

EDIT: Here is what the singleton looks like in C#.

```
public sealed class MySingleton
{
    private static readonly MySingleton instance = new MySingleton();

    private MySingleton() { }

    public static MySingleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
           return instance;
        }
    }

    public BizPaths MyBizPaths = new BizPaths(BizPaths.PathEnvironment.Test);
    public BizDBs MyBizDBs = new BizDBs(DBConfig.DB_Environment.QA);
    public DateTime todaysDate = DBMethods.GetTodaysDate();

}
```

Comment: Can we see more of what you tried (and is broken) in c#?

Comment: `I'm looking at a C# Singleton, but that reinitializes each time the class is called.`  No it doesn't.  If it did, then it wouldn't be a singleton.  Looks like you just want a singleton, or a static class, because yes, you can in fact initialize the values of a static class.

Comment: @gunr2171 I supplied code of what the singleton would look like in C#. I thought it was broken b/c I thought it was reinitializing each time the class was called. Servy says it's not. I'll explain why I thought that in my next comment.

Comment: @Servy You are correct. I misinterpreted when the singleton was initializing.  So maybe this isn't broken. I guess my only question now is does this look like an acceptable way to emualte a module. Sorry, like I said I'm new to C#. (Also new to stackoverflow).

Comment: @dwarn Use it and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one way to emulate a VB module in C# and that's with a static class.  Once compiled, a VB module **IS** a static class, so obviously that's what you should use in C# if you want the same behaviour as a VB module.  The difference is that module members don't have to be qualified with their type name in VB, while C# static class members do require qualification.